# how to make specific text uneditable in JTextarea

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jtextarea, swingx

I am stuck in a very bad situation Kindly help.

My requirement :

- In a text area I will be replacing a String with a value Eg..
  Original text :James Bond acted in Skyfall
- I need to change 'James' alone, with a Tag {CTPC-1} then it will be displaying like "    {CTPC-1} Bond acted in Skyfall" 
  this is done dynamically.. when I select the next string it will be incremented {CTPC-2} etc..
- after replacing it.. the tag "{CTPC-1}" alone should not be editable others i.e "Bond acted in Skyfall"should be  in editable format

  I need to do this in java swings kindly help me

Comment: search for JTextArea and DocumentFilter or NavigationFilter/NavigationFilter.FilterBypass()

Comment: I think you can check it on event "onEdit", and when it happens, you check, if user transform it and if he does, you repair it. It will be virtually unchangable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Protected Text Component](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/protected-text-component/). It will allow you to specify pieces of text that can't be deleted and can also highlight this text.

Comment: Thanks alot... this code is working fine for my work

Comment: Hi camickr..i am able to make a specific text not-editable.. Now after making it not-editable using the Protected Top Component, I want to make it editable, Which i am not able to do it once i change it not-editable.. Kindly help me

Comment: @AlexMichaelRaj, you will need to write your own remove(...) method to remove a specific Position from the Map.